# Google Maps geocoding works on android and desktop but not iOS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am building a react application that relies on the conversion of an address inputted into a text field to a latitude and longitude. To implement this functionality I have used the google maps node library located at - https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js.

The problem started when the application was deployed and I was able to click a button that would in turn convert my text field address into latitude and longitude for other reasons, this was tested on both desktop and Android. However, when I run the application through my phone or any iOS device, the request results in an error response `TypeError: Request header field User-Agent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

The code request responsible for causing this issue is (this.state.address can be as simple as 'HU1'):

```
googleMapsClient.geocode(
      {
        address: this.state.address,
        components: {
          country: 'GB'
        }
      }
```

What I am struggling to understand and therefore work on a fix is why this works on both Android devices and desktop however fails when it is called from an iOS device. Any advice and help is much appreciated.

Thanks